# IntelliJ won't build Android library artifact with two Kotlin plugins applied in the same time

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, artifact

Recently I've encountered an odd problem/bug in IntelliJ IDEA during developing my Android library in Kotlin. I have 2 library modules inside a dummy app. `module1` imports `module2` which has extension functions.

I applied Kotlin plugins into `module1` so the first lines of module's `build.gradle` look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

After that I got the following build error when trying to export the artifact to .jar:

```
Error:Kotlin: Unsupported plugin option: org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:enabled=true
```

What's really weird is that when I remove one of the Kotlin plugins, e.g. `kotlin-android-extensions`, that error no longer occurs. Instead, no extension function from `module2` can be resolved (obviously.)

```
Error:(x, y) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: extensionFunctionFromModule2
```

Other classes can be resolved and everything would work without extension functions.

**Additional info**

When I removed only `kotlin-android` plugin everything was being built successfully... for a very short time. The very next day I suddenly got errors about extension functions' references again.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug of IntelliJ IDEA/Kotlin/Gradle? Seeing that strange behavior (the fact that two Kotlin plugins cannot be applied at the same time) I assume it's some kind of bug. (Maybe caching?) Especially that with application projects everything works just fine. Unfortunately I cannot say how it was working previously as it's my first library project and modules.

**module1's build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(path: ":module2")
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**module2's build.gradle**

The same as module1's but without line with implementations of module2, obviously.

**App's build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.8'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
kotlin.code.style=official
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

**IDE version**

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-192.6603.28, built on September 6, 2019
```

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT with the sample project to reproduce attached.

Comment: Done. For everyone who's struggling with the same problem, here is the issue at YouTrack: [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33855)